# Insert arraylist of checkbox values into mysql rows

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio

I'm trying to insert all of my checked checkbox value in every rows in mysql db, 
once a checkboxes are checked, it is the value that will insert to database with continuous inserting of rows
This is my code but i'm not sure with the insertion of arraylist loop

```
List<String> boxes = new ArrayList<>();

private class Insert extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    TextView mssg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    String cb = String.valueOf(app);
    CheckBox cbapp = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_approver);

    String msg = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urls, user, pass);

            if (conn == null) {
                msg = "Connection went wrong";
            } else if(conn!=null) {

                    String query = "INSERT INTO module_pivot (userID,modID,deptID,formsID) VALUES (99,1,?,0)";
                    PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(query);

                    for (int i=0;i<boxes.size();i++) {
                    prep.setString((i), boxes.get(i));
                }
                    prep.executeUpdate();
                    msg = "Inserted!";

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            msg = "Sql query error";

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        mssg.setText(msg);
    }
}
```

Here is the value of checkbox arraylist, list of departments

```
public void onCheck(View view){

    boolean checked = ((CheckBox)view).isChecked();

    switch (view.getId()){

        case R.id.cbObra:
            if (checked)
                boxes.add("15");
            else
                boxes.remove("15");
            break;
        case R.id.cbBus:
            if (checked)
                boxes.add("14");
            else
                boxes.remove("14");
            break;
        case R.id.cbHR:
            if (checked)
                boxes.add("11");
            else
                boxes.remove("11");
            break;
        case R.id.cbIT:
            if (checked)
                boxes.add("4");
            else
                boxes.remove("4");
            break;
        case R.id.cbMan:
            if (checked)
                boxes.add("7");
            else
                boxes.remove("7");
            break;
        case R.id.cbFin:
            if (checked)
                boxes.add("10");
            else
                boxes.remove("10");
            break;
        case R.id.cbPM:
            if (checked)
                boxes.add("12");
            else
                boxes.remove("12");
            break;
        case R.id.cbCC:
            if (checked)
                boxes.add("84");
            else
                boxes.remove("84");
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a glaring issue:

```
  for (int i=0;i<boxes.size();i++) {
                    prep.setString((i), boxes.get(i));
                }
                    prep.executeUpdate();
```

In that, you are closing your loop before executing your update. Further you should run the update procedure in a transaction. Here's what I think you should be doing:

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
      for (int i=0;i<boxes.size();i++) {
                        prep.setString((i), boxes.get(i));
                        prep.executeUpdate();
                    }
conn.commit();
```

Where conn is your JDBC connection.